# Interpolate variables into external programs call (subprocess.call/Popen) in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to run an external program from a Python script.

After searching and reading multiple post here I came to what seemed to be the solution.

First, I used **subprocess.call** function.

If I build the command this way:

```
hmmer1=subprocess.call("D:\Python_Scripts\HMMer3\hmmsearch.exe --tblout hmmTestTab.out SDHA.hmm Test.fasta")
```

The external program **D:\Python_Scripts\HMMer3\hmmsearch.exe** is run taking **hmmTestTab.out** as file name for the output and **SDHA.hmm** and **Test.fasta** as input files.

Nevertheless, if I try to replace the file names with the variables **outfile**, **hmmprofile** and **fastafile** (*I intend to receive those variables as arguments for the Python script and use them to build the external program call*),

```
hmmer2=subprocess.call("D:\Python_Scripts\HMMer3\hmmsearch.exe --tblout outfile hmmprofile fastafile")
```

Python prints an error about being unable to open the input files.

I also used **"Popen"** function with analogous results:

This call works

```
hmmer3=Popen(['D:\Python_Scripts\HMMer3\hmmsearch.exe', '--tblout','hmmTestTab.out', 'SDHA.hmm','Test.fasta'])
```

and this one doesn't

```
hmmer4=Popen(['D:\Python_Scripts\HMMer3\hmmsearch.exe', '--tblout','outfile', 'hmmprofile','fastafile'])
```

As result of this, I presume I need to understand which is process to follow to interpolate the variables into the call, because it seems that the problem is there.

Would any of you help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
hmmer4=Popen(['D:\Python_Scripts\HMMer3\hmmsearch.exe', '--tblout','outfile', 'hmmprofile','fastafile'])
```

But that's not passing the *variable* `outfile`.  It's passing a *string*, `'outfile'`.

You want:

```
hmmer4=Popen(['D:\Python_Scripts\HMMer3\hmmsearch.exe', '--tblout', outfile, hmmprofile, fastafile])
```

And the other answer is correct, though it addresses a different problem; you should double the backslashes, or use `r''` raw strings.

Comment: thank you very much! Seems that this was the correct combination of simple and double quotes I was looking for!
;)

Comment: Is there an equivalent solution for subprocess.call function?

Comment: Yes there is, because it's the same problem - you're passing the literal string 'outfile' instead of the value of the variable **outfile**. You should be able to pass a list of parameters to subprocess: read the Python docs at https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html or https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html.

Comment: So, this should work, right?


`hmmer2=subprocess.call("D:\\Python_Scripts\\HMMer3\\hmmsearch.exe --tblout outfile hmm fasta") `

But it does not...

Comment: No, why should that work? Once again you are passing the **string** "outfile".

Comment: Dear Daniel, would you please show me how to do the trick , not passing "outfile" as string ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: if it's inside quotes, it's not a variable — it's just a string.  (how would python know you meant a variable there?)  just pass a list to `subprocess.call`

Comment: @Eevee, thank you very much once again, I followed your counsel and it worked.
`hmmer2 = subprocess.call(['D:\Python_Scripts\HMMer3\hmmsearch.exe','--tblout',outfile,hmm,fasta])`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:

```
hmmer1=subprocess.call("D:\Python_Scripts\HMMer3\hmmsearch.exe"
```

to

```
hmmer1=subprocess.call('D:\\Python_Scripts\\HMMer3\\hmmsearch.exe'
```

**Edit**

```
argv = ' --tblout outfile hmmprofile fastafile' # your arguments
program = [r'"D:\\Python_Scripts\\HMMer3\\hmmsearch.exe"', argv]
subprocess.call(program)
```

Comment: first of all, than you very much for your suggestion, but scaping the backslashes doesn't work either. As I said, it works if I pass the full name of the file even without scaping...I still believe it has something to do with the way Python interprets the variables when used inside the call.

Comment: Try my edit, I also had some troubles and ended up with matlab

Comment: Hi Martin, I have tried your edit and I end up with the same error message about python being unable to open the input files...
In other languages like Perl, this kind of calls work nicely, but python is being really difficult for me...